# Nagios Server Unreachable

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I have set up a machine with Centos 7 and installed Nagios from the EPEL repository successfully. Using Lynx (command line browser) I can access the Nagios server running on the machine but it says that the browser must support frames, something Lynx does not do. Now, my issue is when trying to access the server from any other machine in the same LAN. While the machine the server is on in pingable, every request just times out. Also, the requests do not generate any new lines in the access_log and error_log of the apache. Apart from the Nagios service, the same happens when I try to access an index.html file I made as a test on that server (this test file is also accessible from within Lynx locally). I have not tampered with the *.conf files of the apache or the one that Nagios installed. Please help.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the [httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/39tP2xzZ) and the [nagios.conf](http://pastebin.com/gSSSXvfd)

**UPDATE 2:**

As per the request from @MadHatter here is the output from the windows cmd telnet utility:\

```
Connecting To 192.168.10.17...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed
```

**UPDATE 3:**

This is the output from `iptables -L`:

[HERE](http://pastebin.com/8ufvQZPB)

**UPDATE 4:**

This is the output from `iptables -L -n -v`:

[HERE](http://pastebin.com/32vafsQp)

Comment: Can you **edit into your question** the output of `telnet 192.168.10.17 80` from one of the client machines?

Comment: Thanks.  And that is one of the clients from which you say you could open the site with `lynx` - at least, enough to see the frames-related error?  I'm guessing that it's not, that you only tried `lynx` from the NAGIOS server itself.  If that's correct, could you also edit into your question the output of `iptables -L -n -v` on the server?

Comment: @MadHatter Only from the server itself can I use Lynx to see anything. Outside the server I have no access at all.

Comment: So noted.  Then the `iptables `output, please?

Comment: **Please, please** read the question.  I'd very much like the output of `iptables -L -n -v`, not just `iptables -L`.  This system clearly has multiple interfaces, so the difference in output is highly relevant; and I'd like to make a recommendation that *doesn't* completely gut the security on this box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a highly-restrictive (and unnecessarily-complex) set of firewall rules running on that system, which don't currently permit HTTP connections inbound.  Try

```
iptables -A IN_public_allow -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

If this is, as I suspect, a multi-interface system, and you only want to allow connections on the internal NIC, add `-i nicX` to the above command, replacing `nicX` by the logical name of your internal interface (see the output of `ifconfig -a`, or `ip addr show`, for more details).

Comment: This is a single interface machine. Will try the command and report back ASAP.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! http://picpaste.com/72c8fcf398b837ed117394649f31afb1.png

Comment: If I could pester you once more, what is a good entry level resource about iptables?

Comment: I don't blame you for asking, but requests for learning material are **explicitly** off-topic for ServerFault, so I must decline to answer.  (I once wrote a good book on the subject, but it is badly out-of-date and you shouldn't buy it.)

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure that firewalld is disabled. in RHEL7 (centos 7) the default firewall is not iptables but firewalld. You will have to disable it and use iptabls, or use it and remove iptables. try doing the following to disable it:

```
service firewalld stop
chkconfig firewalld off
```

If you want to use firewalld you can open the port using

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp
```