# Centos server will not hold iptables configuration

Tags: iptables, centos7

I have set up a Centos 7 server to run Nagios. By default the OS has pretty draconian iptables rules and a fellow here suggested fixing this by inputing this command:

```
iptables -A IN_public_allow -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

This works fine until I restart the server, at which point I have to input the command again, otherwise the server is unreachable once again.

Is this normal behaviour for iptables? Can I do something to fix it?

Comment: With earlier versions of CentOS, it depended on how you had the system configured.  With 7, they have architected a whole different way of setting up a firewall (though it's still just setting up `iptables` rules under the hood), and you'll have to work within the constraints of `firewalld` (which I don't yet have experience with).

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756240/how-can-i-use-iptables-on-centos-7

Comment: @unlink I followed the instructions in the stackoverflow article and now I lost connectivity again to my server. Also, the command I used to input to fix  the issue does not work any more. Instead I get "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name"

Comment: **Please, before anyone else posts `service iptables save`**, note that the OP is using CentOS 7 - and that is `firewalld`-based, and therefore `service iptables save` doesn't work.

Comment: @MadHatter Apologies. I reverted the changes and everything works. I even deleted the offending comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CentOS 7 uses [firewalld](http://fedorahosted.org/firewalld) by default to manage the firewall.

You can simply add the port to firewalld with:

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent     # Startup config
firewall-cmd --add-service=http                 # Running config
```

Answer (score -2):

That will cetainly "fix" "fairly draconian rules" - but creates a singificant security hole in your system and is far from efficient.

Really you should be inserting 2 rules at the start of the chain - the first rule should allow related and established packets in (any port) and one to allow new packets in to port 80.

Its a bad idea to play with iptables directly unless you really know what you are doing. The firewall is loaded from /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config at start up. Its a bad idea to edity this unless you really know what you're doing.

If you read the manual then you would know that you could make iptables changes persist by running `/sbin/service iptables save` but this is predicating on manually changing the iptables rules.

I don't have a centos machine handy to check, but if it a straight clone of RHEL, then it should have a GUI tool called firewall-config which allows for changes to be made without breaking stuff.

Comment: sy, I take your point, but it's worth looking at the original question.  The very first rule in his entire `INPUT` chain permits *all* ESTABLISHED traffic, so no packet in any given web connection except the original `NEW` is ever going to get as far as this rule.  As for `service iptables save`, **please** read the note above about this being C7.

Comment: @madhatter, I see no mention of what is currently in the chain in the original question.

Comment: The "*original question*" isn't the one above, it's the one he refers to - rather obliquely - in the second sentence of this question.  You have to trawl through the OP's history to see it; it's at http://serverfault.com/questions/633030/nagios-server-unreachable .  I know that's not very helpful.  Sorry.